# Facebook Chatbot postback not working

Tags: php, facebook, postback, chatbot

I've setup a working facebook chatbot in PHP and built a generic template carousel with one of the postback buttons being:

```
[
type"=>"postback",
"title"=>"Opening Hours",
"payload"=>"Opening Hours"                                                                                              
],
```

Pressing the postback button and checking my PHP logs I am getting:

```
{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"457107221010xxx","time":1513219207386,
    "messaging": [{"recipient":
              {"id":"457107221010xxx"},"timestamp":1513219207386,"sender":
              {"id":"1510264525690xxx"},"postback":{"payload":"Opening 
            Hours","title":"Opening Hours"}}]}]}
```

I'm handling this postback in my code by:

```
$postback = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['postback']['payload'];
if ($postback!="") {
 $answer = ["text"=> $openingHours];
}
```

But in messenger window after pressing said postback button, messenger seem to be "typing" with the three dots dialog showing for a few seconds, but then it just stops without any replies.  I did enable "message_postback" option in webhooks, and other queries are working (e.g. if I type "Opening Hours" manually I'll get the Opening Hours reply).  I process other queries with following code and it works:

```
$sender     = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$message    = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
if(preg_match('[opening|hours]', strtolower($message))) {
        $answer =     ["text"=>"
                Opening Hours:
10:30 am – 1:00 am (Sun-Thu)"];
} else {
   //show menu
}
```

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: well, I've same problem still dont know how to fix it

Comment: Our problems are solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I dont see the code, which triggers the actual sending, the error could be found there. If you've copied the basic tutorial it might look like this one I started with a long time ago:

```
if(preg_match('[time|current time|now]', strtolower($message))) {
    $message_to_reply = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
} else {
    $message_to_reply = 'Huh! what do you mean?';
}

// your code here
$postback = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['postback']['payload'];
if ($postback!="") {
    $message_to_reply = "postback!";
    $foundPostback = true;
}

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/messages?access_token='.$access_token;
$ch = curl_init($url);
$jsonData = '{
    "recipient":{
        "id":"'.$sender.'"
    },
    "message":{
        "text":"'.$message_to_reply.'"
    }
}';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

if(!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']) || $foundPostback ){
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Notice the `$foundPostback`. If your send trigger looks like this from one the tutorials, it will not send messages, as there is no `$input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']`attribute in postback messages. So if you detect a postback, you have to keep that flag.

---

[image]

---

However, I strongly suggest to build own classes for handling messages, postback, deliveries, echos and so on. More about those you can find here: [Facebook Messenger Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to point that out!  That was the problem indeed!