# php chatbot postback payload not working when using elseif

Tags: php

I'm making a Facebook chatbot and try to use postback payload but it didn't work , I have also checked in my log.

Everything prints the right value but it didn't enter my else if block.

**My Code**

```
$sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
$message_to_reply = '';
$payload = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['postback']['payload'];
$fp = file_put_contents( 'request.log', date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."PAYLOAD = ".$payload, FILE_APPEND);

if (strpos($message, 'hi') != '') {
  $message_to_reply = 'hi';
  $jsonData = '{
    "recipient":{
      "id":"' . $sender . '"
    },
    "message":{
      "text":"'.$message_to_reply.'",
    },
  }';

} elseif(strpos($payload, 'test') != '') {
  $message_to_reply = 'PAYLOAD DIDNT WORK';
  $jsonData = '{
    "recipient":{
      "id":"' . $sender . '"
     },
    "message":{
      "text":"'.$message_to_reply.'",
    },
  }';

} else {
  $message_to_reply= 'CHOOSE MENU';
  $jsonData = '{
    "recipient":{
      "id":"'. $sender.'"
    },
    "message":{
      "attachment":{
        "type":"template",
        "payload":{
          "template_type":"button",
          "text":"'.$message_to_reply.'",
          "buttons":[
            {
              "type":"web_url",
              "url":"https://petersapparel.parseapp.com",
              "title":"PROMOTION"
            },
            {
              "type":"postback",
              "title":"test",
              "payload":"test"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }';
}
```

My if and else block works fine but when I click on button test, I get value `$payload = 'test'` but I don't know why it didn't enter the elseif block.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Does your logic work properly when `$payload = 'hi';` ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay not working when i  change payload test to hi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your condition like this:

```
if (strpos($message, 'hi') !== false)

elseif(strpos($payload, 'test') !== false) // As 0th position is considered as '' in if condition which you are comparing.
```

Comment: @test1321, I have updated my answer. Use `!==` with your conditions. It will work.

Comment: still not working , If I type hi it return hi which work, but when i click button  test, it return noting and I already check my $payload in my log $payload return ' test' which is the right value

Comment: I can not solve your form issue. But If you check inside the conditions using `print_r();die;` to debug, you can confirm that now your conditions will work according to the strings you will pass.

Comment: Oh so my solution worked. You should accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you commenting in another question. Maybe my answer solves your problem as well? It is not about detecting, but trigger the sending of a message containing a postback.

See here: [Facebook Chatbot postback not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805187/facebook-chatbot-postback-not-working/47846473#47846473)

In addition, make sure, you have postbacks checked in the webhook section of your app.

[image]

Cheers